# In R, how do I modify a dataframe column in a list given a string name

Tags: r, non-standard-evaluation

I'm new to R. Thank you for your patience. I'm working with the survey package.

**Background**: I'm writing a function that loops through combinations of predictor and outcome variables (i.e., `svyglm(outcome~predictor)`) in a complex survey to output crude prevalence ratios. For each outcome/predictor combination, I want to first relevel the predictor within the survey design object to ensure the output ratios are all > 1.

**Specific problem**: Given the survey design object name, column name and reference level as strings, how do I tell R I want said column releveled.

prams16 is the name of the survey design object which includes a list of 9 items, variables is the analytic dataset (data frame) within the survey design object and mrace is a column in the variables DF.

These work:

```
prams16$variables$mrace <- relevel(prams16$variables$mrace, ref="White")
prams16[["variables"]]["mrace"] <- relevel(prams16$variables$mrace, ref="White")
```

However, when I try to construct references to `prams16$variables$mrace` or `prams16[["variables"]]["mrace"]` with strings, nothing seems to work.

Thanks!

EDIT: Requested reproducible example of problem.

```
myPredictor <- as.factor(c("Red","White","Black","Red","Green","Black","White","Black","Red","Green","Black"))
myOutcome <- c(1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1)
myDF <- tibble(myPredictor, myOutcome)
myOtherStuff <- c("etc","etc")
myObj <- list(myDF=myDF,myOtherStuff=myOtherStuff)


#These work...
myObj$myDF$myPredictor <- relevel(myObj$myDF$myPredictor, ref="White")
str(myObj$myDF$myPredictor) #"White" is now the referent level

myObj[["myDF"]]["myPredictor"] <- relevel(myObj$myDF$myPredictor, ref="Red")
str(myObj$myDF$myPredictor) #"Red" is now the referent level

#How to construct relevel assignment statement from strings?
anObj <- "myObj"
aPredictor <- "myPredictor"
aRef <- "Green"

#Produces error
as.name(paste0(anObj,"$myDF$",aPredictor)) <- relevel(as.name(paste0(anObj,"$myDF$",aPredictor)), ref=aRef)
```

Comment: You said `prams16[["variables"]]["mrace"]` works?

Comment: @akrun, Yes, the statement  `prams16[["variables"]]["mrace"] <- relevel(prams16$variables$mrace, ref="White")` correctly relevels the factor `mrace`.

Comment: Can you update with a small reproducible example with `dput` and expected output

Comment: I'm not sure how to use dput in this instance, but I added a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to solve this using expression arithmetic. Our task is to construct and evaluate the following expression:

```
myObj$myDF[[aPredictor]] <- relevel( myObj$myDF[[aPredictor]], ref=aRef )
```

**Step 1:** Convert the string `"myObj"` to a symbolic name:

```
sObj <- rlang::sym(anObj)      # Option 1
sObj <- as.name(anObj)         # Option 2
```

**Step 2:** Construct the expression `myObj$myDF[[aPredictor]]`:

```
e1 <- rlang::expr( (!!sObj)$myDF[[aPredictor]] )
```

Here, we use `!!` to tell `rlang::expr` that we want to replace `sObj` with whatever symbol is stored inside that variable. Without `!!`, the expression would be `sObj$myDF[[aPredictor]]`, which is not quite what we want.

**Step 3:** Construct the target expression:

```
e2 <- rlang::expr( !!e1 <- relevel(!!e1, ref=aRef) )
```

As before, `!!` replaces `e1` with whatever expression is stored inside it (i.e., what we constructed in Step 2).

**Step 4:** Evaluate the expression and inspect the result:

```
eval.parent(e2)

## The column is now correctly releveled to Green
myObj$myDF$myPredictor
#   [1] Red   White Black Red   Green Black White Black Red   Green Black
#  Levels: Green Black Red White
```